# cmake error [CMake Error at SDK/Util/CMakeLists.txt:132 (add_library)]

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

The following error occurs when the cmake that was running in a Windows environment is performed on Linux:

Error message is
(CMake GUI generate button click error message):

> CMake Error at SDK/A/Util/CMakeLists.txt:132 (add_library): 
>   Target "Util" links to target "VSI::GL" but the target was not found. 
>   Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
>
> CMake Error at SDK/B/Vis/CMakeLists.txt:424 (add_library): 
>   Target "Util" links to target "VSI::GL" but the target was not found. 
>   Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?

The SDK/A/Util/CMakeLists.txt:132 is:

```
    add_library(Util ${STATIC_OR_SHARED} ${UTIL_PROJECT_FILES}) 
    set_target_properties(Util PROPERTIES 
      FOLDER "SDK" 
      PROJECT_LABEL "SDK - Util" 
    ) 
    ApplySDKVersion(Util) 
    target_include_directories(Util PUBLIC 
      $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..> 
      $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include> 
    ) 
    target_link_libraries(Util PUBLIC Vis Data Core) 
    target_link_libraries(Util PRIVATE VSI::GL) 
    if(UTIL_SHARED) 
      target_compile_definitions(Util PRIVATE Util_LIB_EXPORT_SHARED) 
    else() 
      target_compile_definitions(Util PUBLIC Util_LIB_EXPORT_STATIC) 
    endif()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks for reading!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

It was a problem with the external program.

In my case it was an OpenGL version issue.

thank you for read!

---

**additional infomation**

I was using vmware.
vmware supports only openGL version 2.1 (not pro version)

So, after installing Centos myself, update the opengl version, the program worked fine.

I hope it helps a lot!